# Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 for Hangman game

Tags: java

Why the console said `Index 0 out of bounds for length 0`?
It says in my method `CharacterSearch()`.

Here is my code. By the way the code is Hangman Game. I am new to java and don't know all the libraries included.

```java
package besingaPi_LE_3_2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameHangman {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int miss = 0; 
        String choice1;
        String temp;
        
        String[] words = {"giraffe", "hipopotamus", "gorilla", "peacock", "armadillo"};

        int choice;
        //do {
            mainMenu();
            choice = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
            if(choice == 1){
                
                String wordRandom = Randomizer(words);
//              char[] letters = new char[wordRandom.length()];
                String mute  = secretWord(wordRandom);
                temp = mute;
//              char c = wordRandom.charAt(3);
//              System.out.println(c);
                System.out.println(wordRandom);
                System.out.println("Note: use only small character/s");
                
                while(!mute.equals(wordRandom)) {
                    System.out.print("(Guess) Enter a letter in word " + mute + " > ");         
                    choice1 = input.nextLine();
//                  char letter = choice1.charAt(0);
                    mute = CharacterSearch(wordRandom, mute, choice1);

                    if(temp.equals(mute)) {
                        miss++;
                    }
                    temp = mute;
    
                }
                System.out.println("The word is " + wordRandom + "." + " You missed " + miss + " time.");
            }
            else if (choice == 0) {
                System.out.println("Thank you!!");
                return;
            }

    }
    public static void mainMenu() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman");  
        System.out.println("[1]START\n[0]EXIT"); 
        System.out.print("Please input your choice: ");
        return; 
    }
    public static String CharacterSearch(String word, String muted, String key) {
        StringBuilder update = new StringBuilder(muted);
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if(word.charAt(i)  == key.charAt(0)) {
                update.setCharAt(i,key.charAt(0));
            }
        }
        
        muted = update.toString();
        return muted;
    }
    public static String secretWord(String word) {
        String temp = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            temp += "*";
        }
        return temp;
    }
    
    public static String Randomizer(String[] words) {
        int rand = (int)(Math.random() * words.length);
        String word = words[rand];
        return word;
    }
}
```

I tried so many things but it will always say Index out of Bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Index 0 out of bounds for length 0" error you're encountering is probably because of `input.nextLine()` call after reading an integer input using `input.nextInt()`. When you press Enter after entering the integer, the `input.nextLine()` reads the newline character ('\n'), which your code didn't capture.

To fix this, you can add an extra `input.nextLine()` after reading the integer to consume the newline character. Modify your code like this:

```java
choice = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
System.out.println();
if (choice == 1) {
    // ...
}
```

This should prevent the error now. Don't worry, I used to make this mistake all the time.

Comment: Thank you for this my code now works. But one question if I opt the System.out.println(); part, I will also opt the input.nextLine();

Comment: @PioloPascualBesinga Yes, if you choose to remove the System.out.println(); line, you can also remove the corresponding input.nextLine(). Also, if your code works now please accept this answer - so other people will know this question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add System.out.println right in front of the problematic code and check the content of the strings word and key and comment out the for loop for now. This way you can check whether the word and key strings are as you expect them to be.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... why the console said Index 0 out of bounds for length 0. ..."*

The *choice1* value is empty.

Calling *input.nextLine()* after having called *input.nextInt()* will simply move the *Scanner* cursor to the next line.

For example, imagine you requested the user to enter 3 numbers on one line.
You would use *nextInt* 3 times, and then *nextLine* once, to advance to the next line.

Here is the cursor position, for each call.

```
Enter 3 values:  100 200 300
                  ^   ^   ^
^                 |   |   |
|         nextInt 1   |   nextInt 3
|                     |
nextLine          nextInt 2
```

Call *nextLine* after the *choice* assignment.

```java
choice = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
```

Here is an example output.
Hippopotamus is spelled incorrectly, also.

```
Welcome to Hangman
[1]START
[0]EXIT
Please input your choice: 1

hipopotamus
Note: use only small character/s
(Guess) Enter a letter in word *********** > h
(Guess) Enter a letter in word h********** > i
(Guess) Enter a letter in word hi********* > p
(Guess) Enter a letter in word hip*p****** > o
(Guess) Enter a letter in word hipopo***** > t
(Guess) Enter a letter in word hipopot**** > a
(Guess) Enter a letter in word hipopota*** > m
(Guess) Enter a letter in word hipopotam** > u
(Guess) Enter a letter in word hipopotamu* > s
The word is hipopotamus. You missed 0 time.
```